# MongoDB query iteration taking time and ending with error

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework

I have collection which looks like below.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd69c4556487e05908378b9"),
    "id" : 1,
    "mobile_number" : NumberLong(9110568960),
    "operator" : 0,
    "circle" : 12,
    "upload_file_id" : 1,
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd69c4556487e05908378ba"),
    "id" : 2,
    "mobile_number" : NumberLong(9176662027),
    "operator" : 13,
    "circle" : 4,
    "upload_file_id" : 1,
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd69c4556487e05908378bb"),
    "id" : 3,
    "upload_id" : 3,
    "mobile_number" : NumberLong(9160228877),
    "operator" : 13,
    "circle" : 1,
    "upload_file_id" : 1,
}
```

There are 10 million mobile numbers like above in MongoDB.
I want take only mobile number from MongoDB. So Django code will be like below.

This is taking time and also ending with different error. I am new to django and MongoDB.

```
# fetching only mobile number from DB.  
query = upload.objects.mongo_aggregate([{'$project': {'mobile_number':'$mobile_number'}}] )   
query_list = []  
for i in query:  
   query_list.append(i['mobile_number']) #adding only mobile numbers in list.
```

Error is : Sometime i am getting CursorNotFound error and sometime MasterNotFound error.

Comment: if it is possible can you share your error?

Comment: in any case if you try to iterate mongo cursor with 10m records it will be take some time (1m ~ 30s).

Comment: Try to query wit this filter {'$project': {'mobile_number':1, '_id':0}}

Comment: Hi, i have updated my error.